# Equivalent of a VLOOKUP in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I've been struggling through this for a few hours as a newbie to Tableau, so after quite a few searches, I figured I'd give a post a shot.

I have two data sources: a database on a Tableau server and an Excel file.  The database has sales information (product number, quantity, order number, order date, etc...) and the Excel file has a list of product numbers (not even close to inclusive to all our product numbers) and a designation - for simplicity, I'll say A and B.  The A products need to go out the door in 2 days and the B products need to go out the door in 5 days.  Everything that's left is a C and needs to go out the door in 15 days.

I created a measure to pull in the A/B/C designation into the primary sheet with my database (below):

Measure Name: Program Status

```
IF ATTR([Direct (Direct SKUs)].[Program]) = "A" THEN "A"

ELSEIF ATTR([Direct (Direct SKUs)].[Program]) = "B" THEN "B"

ELSE "C"

END
```

Works all fine and great - displays on a table perfectly.  I did spot check a few and as far as I can tell, everything mapped ok.  The problem is the second step...

Dimension Name: Program Compliance

```
IF [Program Status] = "A" AND [Cycle Time to Ship (Weekdays)] >=2.000001 THEN "Late"

ELSEIF [Program Status] = "B" AND [Cycle Time to Ship (Weekdays)] >=5.000001 THEN "Late"

ELSEIF [Program Status] = "C" AND [Cycle Time to Ship (Weekdays)] >=15.000001 THEN "Late"

ELSE

"On Time"

END'''
```

With the above code, I get errors because I'm mixing aggregate and non-aggregate functions.  I'll be honest and say I have no idea where to go next...  I don't know if I need to retool the "Program Status" measure, change something for "Program Compliance", or maybe this isn't feasible with Tableau.  I'm much more familiar with Power BI and there were some things you just couldn't do.

I did validate the Excel file only has unique values for the Product Numbers, so I should have a one-to-many between that and the sales data.

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: Please upload your data sample here, at least a few rows! The vlookup isn't needed here because you can join two tables

Comment: I will try to cleanse the data (since it is customer info) and put some examples of the data in an Excel file.  One thing I forgot to add to my post was that since I am using a Tableau Server for the one database, I am unable to join with anything.  I've done several searches on line and it seems to be pretty unanimous that it can't be done, but if a workaround exists, I'd gladly give it a try.

Comment: Do try `IN` in tableau desktop with If then else end condition.  I'm it will solve your problem without joining.

Comment: See this https://www.flerlagetwins.com/2020/09/in-operator-generator-case-statement.html?m=1

Answer (score 0):

There is a small problem in your calculation.  You are creating a new column in existing table, perhaps, instead of joining two tables.  Let me show this through sample superstore dataset with tableau.  I have created a new excel table with few product IDs and designation.

Step-1: For sake of understanding products where name start with A are desig A and products starting with B are B and everything else is not included in table (your C).

step-2: Import this table in tableau same sheet and connect like following screenshot.
[image]

Now you have successfully mapped your both tables just like `vlookup` in excel does.  Null values you can map to C either through intermediate calculation or directly.

[image]

Hope this helps.  Else please upload your sheet.

Comment: I am using a Tableau Server as the source for the one database, so I don't think joining is feasible.  I can join the Excel file with other sources, but I cannot join the Tableau Server - the searches I did online seemed to confirm this, but maybe someone knows a workaround?

Comment: About Server version i am not that much aware.  If you are using latest version of desktop version of Tableau u can, in that case make use of IN operator.  If you still have a long list of values you can use IN statement generator, available on FlerlageTwins blog.  See If that helps